# Why doesn't extruding from some edges make a face while usually it does?

Tags: extrude

[image: Picture 1 & Picture 2]

The first picture is when I extruded after selecting two vertices and it gave me an additional face, three edges and two vertices as you can see.
But the second picture is when I extruded after selecting (some)two vertices and it gave me no faces and only additional two edges.

It seems like if I select one already extruded vertex and one that I didn't, the second scenario happens. 
Why? And how do I make a new face in the latter case?

Answer (score 2):

Can you confirm that you select the **connected vertices** rather than a duplicated one?

You can use indices indicator to show the vertices. Than you should check which vertex you choose to extrude. If you select two separated vertices, they won't automatically connected with face and edge since it is impossible and unusual.

[image]

You might accidentally exit the extrude mode with <kbd>RMB</kbd>, it will create the vertices in the same place. Causing extra vertices that user might not noticed.

Comment: How do I open that tab?

Comment: All I can see is until the 'geometry' part. The afterward things (Tracks, Mesh Edit Mode, Developer, Measurement, Normals, Freestyle) doesn't appear to me.

Comment: @김준형 You need to enter **mesh edit** mode to see those option

Comment: ...and to see indices, 'Developer Extras' must be checked in Edit > Preferences > Interface..

Comment: @RobinBetts Sorry, my bad. I didn't notice that difference...(I thought everyone will check that option)

Comment: ..and to make the indices actually _visible_, you can change their color: it's 'Face Angle Text' in the Theme > 3D View.,, But the  'MeasureIt' add-on gives better options.

Comment: @Hikariztw Sorry :c I can't find any 'mesh edit mode' button. I do not know what that is.

Comment: @김준형 `Tab`, change between object and edit mode.